# Adding and Delete Edittexts using soft keybord

Tags: android

I have editText and button "add" and "del" in every item of listView. So, user can add new editTexts and delete old.

Button takes a lot of place. I think about to delete them and to use softKeyobord whith button "add" and "del". Is it real to create my own buttons in the soft keyboard? 
My Target Sdk Version="19".
In this case setOnKeyListener don't work:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = convertView;


    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemadd, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addtospintextView1);
    viewHolder.value=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addtospineditText1);

    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.value.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Hi");
            return true;
        }


    });


    return view;
}



static class ViewHolder {
      TextView name;
      EditText value;
    }
```

}

Also, I don't know how my own buttons in the soft keyboard will be work at different android's phone...

Answer (score 0):

You should not encumber your screen with so much buttons: you should register your items for a **ContextMenu**.

The **ContextMenu** appears in a foating window (on pre-HoneyComb 3.0 API) and in a **contextual ActionBar** that overlays the Activity's ActionBar to present the items of the contextual menu.The screen is then in **contextual action mode**.

If you register a ListView for a ContextMenu, it will automatically register its items.